# how to remove string from the text and leave the int values only in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several different products on my page from which i am retrieving the values and adding to the cart now i want to calculate the total it give me an error of NaN so how can i remove this NaN from the string to satisfy the NaN and able to calculate the sum of the products here is my code.

```
<div class="left-top">
        <ul class="add">

        </ul>
        <ul style="float:right">
    <li id="total">0.0</li>
        </ul>
     </div>

  <div class="right-bottom">
     <div class="box2">
         <p>pkr 800.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 700.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverges</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <p>pkr 800.0</p>
       <img src="images/col.png" />
       <h1>Beverg</h1>
     </div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box2').click(function(){
      //alert($(".add li:first").html());
      var price=$( this).find('p').html();
      var product=$( this).find('h1').html();
      //adding the values

      var price1=$(this).find('p').html();    
      var currentValue=parseInt($("#total").text());
      var newValue =parseInt(currentValue) + price1;
      $("#total").text(newValue);
      //end of adding values
       if(product)
       {
           if($(".add li:first").html()== undefined)
                { 
                 $('<li>', {html: price}).prependTo('.add');
                 $('<li>', {html: product}).prependTo('.add');

                }
           else
                {
                 $('<li>', {html: product}).appendTo('.add');
                 $('<li>', {html: price}).appendTo('.add'); 
                }
       }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle for that

Comment: Two things: The second argument of `parseInt` is ***NOT*** optional. But you're trying to parse a float (`0.0`) anyway so you should use `parseFloat` (which doesn't have a second argument)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hM848/ js fiddle of my webpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add data-value={price} to your p tag and parse that?

```
<p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>    

<li id="total" data-vlue="0">$0</li>

var tot = parseInt($( this).find('p').attr('data-value')) 
+ parseInt($('#total').attr('data-value'));
$('#total').attr('data-value', tot);
$('#total').html('$' + tot);
```

Comment: I support this as an answer.

Comment: With jQuery you can use the `data()` method like this: `$(this).find('p').data('value')`.  It reads the data attribute as well as any data bound to the element by JavaScript.

Comment: looks like the shortest way to reach the correct result thanks

Comment: @Vicky In case you don't want the data attribute (even though it is the best solution), here the code you could use : `var price1 = parseInt($(this).find('p').html().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));`

Comment: i have done like this but still is not adding instead of adding it replace the last selected value   var price1=$(this).find('p').attr('data-value');   
   var currentValue=0;
   var newValue =parseInt(currentValue)+price1;
   $("#total").text(newValue);

Comment: You need to parseInt the $(this).find('p').attr('data-value') since you're trying to add to a parseInt(currentValue)

Comment: update your answer because your answer is meaningful for getting the dynamic data please update it

Comment: i have tried parseInt on each n every thing but still it replacing instead of adding i am intrested in your answer because for dynamic data is perfect please update your answer

Comment: add a data-value attribute to your li id="total" tag and stash the running total there.

Comment: Thanks alot dear i was near to done it but you are so fast thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RTeKC/
{

```
price1 = price1.replace("pkr ","") * 1;
var currentValue=parseInt($("#total").text());
```

}

Only you replace "pkr " by ""
after
multiply the result by 1 to obtain an integer

Comment: This one is correct and accurate any how thanks to all friends

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the question, I would go with Mark S's answers, thats more cleaner way of implementing it. But if you don't wanna change your data.  Here's a way to do it using the original structure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    findTot();
});

function findTot(){
   var total =0;
   $(".right-bottom").find("p").each(function(){
      total += parseInt($(this).html().split(" ")[1]);
   });
   $("#total").html(total);
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nXW2L/)'s a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXW2L/) if you wanna check it.